# Responsive header with dropdown menu: height and overflow

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, hidden

I need a responsive header, which changes height depending on the screen resolution and wrapping of the elements. As the screen gets smaller, the menu wraps below my logo (which is desirable) and the height of the header has to increase. Obviously, I have set the properties of the header to `height: auto` and `overflow: hidden` and this will do the trick.

The problem is: I am using a dropdown menu. Using `height: auto` and `overflow: hidden` instead of a fixed height for the header, makes the dropdown items well... hidden of course.

My question is now: what is the best way to solve this? Solutions with pure CSS preferred.

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: I think the description is quite clear: the height of the header needs to depend on the content (for which you usually use 'overflow:hidden'), but still show dropdown items from the menu that is in the header. If it isn't clear enough, I will post some code tomorrow.

Comment: But could you show some code please? Without it, I have no idea what I'm supposed to be working with.

Comment: I would have, but the answer of sherrifderek shows exactly what the solution to the problem  is! Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a clear-fix instead of the overflow hidden. You want to clear the floats, and not actually hide the overflow. Read about that here:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
<header class="clear-fix"></header>
```

There are more elegant ways if you use a preprocessor etc.

```
.clear-fix:before,
.clear-fix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clear-fix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dewNT/) that should help.

Comment: Wow, that is perfect! Such a simple solution after so many hours of trying to work around the hidden overflow. I am really glad with this @sherrifderek, the responsiveness of my site is really coming together now :) Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Good luck! Yeah, take a second look at stuff like `overflow hidden` - there are many things like that that people get used to because of short answers on here, because they are easy - but people don't understand how they work - and end up causing all sorts of problems.

Comment: @sherrifderek: I have a late follow-up question! :) With this solution the header is responsive (which is still the priority), but since my header has a 5px border with the dropdown items being underneath, there now is 5px unclickable margin in which a visitor can 'lose' the dropdown if he is not fast enough navigating from the menu item to the dropdown items. Do you mind having a look at http://www.purasol.co.cr/v2/ and tell me if there are any solutions to this? I can't just increase the link margin of the menu items since the border now wraps around it.